# Why webpack chunks loads from my_domain.com but not from localhost:8080 when using webpack development server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

I'am using `webpack` in my project. When Javascript bundle has become large, I decide to split code with `react-loadable` dynamic imports, for example

```
...
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';

const LoadablePage = Loadable({

    loader: () => import('./page'),
    loading: Loading,
});

class Main extends Component {

    render () {

        return (<LoadablePage/>);
    }
}
```

When I'am opening `http://my_domain.com` page, browser successfully load `index.js` from `http://localhost:8080/build/test/index.js`. Then try to load `0.js` chunk from `http://my_domain.com/build/0.js`.

But `0.js` is not exists in `http://my_domain.com/build/0.js` location, it can be successfully loaded from `http://localhost:8080/build/0.js`.

How to correctly specify domain for load chunks while developing?

### Webpack config

```
module.exports = {

    entry: {

        'test/index': [ 'babel-polyfill', './resources/assets/modules/test/index', ],
    },
    output: {

        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public/build/'),
        publicPath: '/build/',
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].js',
    },
    ...
    devServer: {

        contentBase: './build/',
        proxy: [{

            path: '/',
            target: 'http://localhost',
            port: 8080,
        }],
    },
    ...
}
```

### Page template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8080/build/test/index.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="http://localhost:8080/build/test/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```